# Goofed; have two accounts; how to merge?

Tags: support

I occasionally browse the "hot network questions" and found one in EL&U, which allowed me to post an answer even though I wasn't a member at the time. Somehow, I managed to get [this unregistered account](https://stackexchange.com/users/11305303/jeff-zeitlin) created, *and* I've joined under *this* account - can I get the two accounts (and their rep) merged to *this* account (and if so, how)?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! You will find the answer in *[How do I connect my account to itself?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6733/how-do-i-connect-my-account-to-itself)*, which is really just a link to the help, which just sends you to the [contact page](https://english.stackexchange.com/contact) to explain what happened so that a staff member can do the merge.

Comment: @choster - thanks; that's what I needed. Not sure why that wasn't suggested as a possible same question when I was posting this one...